# How to determine the "post type" of a "page"

Tags: wordpress

I've created a Wordpress template for a site and the site uses an events plugin. My template has a custom heading so in the header it displays different text according to the post-type.

I'm having difficulty with the plugin (The Events Calendar) however it isn't a plugin issue. I'm unable to determine if it is a "tribe_events" post type becuase the plugin generates a page so when I use the get_post_type() function, it returns that it is a page. How do you get the underlying post type of a page? Is it possible without having to write a direct MySQL or $wpdb query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not the most efficient way to do this but I've resorted to using $wp_query->post and then using the available fields from the post.

```
global $wp_query;
$postObj = $wp_query->post;
```

Now I can use any of the available fields from $postObj

Answer (score 0):

You can use global $post object to get post type.

```
global $post;
$post_type = $post->post_type;
```

var_dump($post); to check content of the object.

Comment: Wow, it's so obvious I'm embarrassed! It's a much better solution than what I'd settled for. Thank you!

Comment: Turns out I was too optimistic as your solution returns "0" values for all items in the post array. Had to revert to the solution I posted below.